# Finding path to "reminder.app" on Mac terminal (non-English localization)

Tags: python, macos, localization, subprocess, popen

I am using a Macbook Air on Big Sur 11.2.2, with language set to Japanese.

I was trying to launch "reminder.app" using subprocess.Popen( ) on Python 3.8.5. interactive shell. But I am unable to launch the Reminders.app even if I use the Japanese app name indicated (along with Calculator.app , Dictionary.app and many others that are shown in Japanese app names). I am however able to launch apps I installed.

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['open', '/Applications/Reminders.app/'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7ffa8e233e80>
The file /Applications/Reminders.app does not exist.

>>> subprocess.Popen(['open', '/Applications/リマインダー.app/']) # Japanese name of app
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7ffa8e233d60>
The file /Applications/リマインダー.app does not exist.

subpsubprocess.Popen(['open', '/Applications/Safari.app/'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7ffa8e233bb0>
# success!
```

I have checked using Finder, and all the applications I am looking for are shown in the GUI interface, albeit given Japanese names. However, these apps simply cannot be found on terminal command line nor manipulated, even with `ls -a`.

How can I find the path to the Reminders app, with the intent of using it with subprocess.Popen() ?

Is it not possible to do so because I am using a non-English system language?

Comment: Opening Reminders and Safari worked for me.  So you're saying that the command `ls -a /Applications` doesn't show Reminders? but it does for other applications? Does `Popen` work for the Applications you can see with `ls`

Comment: All of the standard applications that come with macOS are in `/System/Applications`, not in `/Applications`.  I think Finder does a trick to list them when you open the Applications folder in it.  But if you `ls -al /Applicatons`, none of the standard programs are listed.  `ls -al /System/Applicatons` will show them.

Comment: @silicontrip - yes, it does works for applications that I can see.

Comment: @ChipJarred - thanks! they really are in that folder you specified! interesting trick that Apple did here...

Comment: @chipjarrred which version of the OS is that? I don't have a /System/Applications on any of my machines.

Comment: @silicontrip In my case it's Catalina (10.15.6), but it should be the same on Big Sur.   In fact, unless your macOS is really old, you should have `/System/Applications` on your Mac. I know in early OS X versions, all the apps, including the standard ones, were in `/Applications`, but I don't remember when they changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch it, rather than just find it, you can try this command line:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Reminders" to activate'
```

I don't know if you can substitute the Japanese name, but it's worth a try.  So from Python:

```
import os
os.system('osascript -e \'tell application \"Reminders\" to activate\'')
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/osascript', '-e', 'tell application \"Reminders\" to activate'])
```

The `osascript` command is basically running the small AppleScript in the single quotes.  I haven't tried doing anything more complicated, but I assume, being an Apple program, that it supports all sorts of AppleEvents so you can probably do cool things like actual schedule a reminder using an AppleScript from your Python code.

Comment: While this does work, but I wanted it to work using python code. That's why I wanted the path. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: I understood that you intend to call it from Python.  I was thinking you'd use Python to call the command line I gave.  I've updated my answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

With this command :

```
find / -xdev -name Reminders.app 2> /dev/null
```

You'll find : /System/Applications/Reminders.app

Comment: Thanks for the advice! They are indeed in the folder you specified, although I wasn't able to get the same results with the command you provided. Somehow, even with sudo, all I got was a loong chain of "find: <folder> permission denied" and "find: <folder> operation not permitted". I'll need to study up what went wrong.

Comment: Updated, just avoid "permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the path for any app bundle id with [mdfind](https://manp.gs/mac/1/mdfind):

```bash
$ mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'com.apple.reminders'"
/System/Applications/Reminders.app
```

If you don't know the bundle id for an app:

```bash
$ osascript -e 'id of app "Reminders"'
com.apple.reminders
```